# Why .Net has no generic version of Thread.Start()?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am wondering why .Net does not have a generic method for starting a thread.

For example we start a thread like following....

```
Thread th = new Thread(SayHello);
th.Start("Hello");

private static void SayHello(object obj)
        {
            string str = obj as string;
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
```

Why can't we have I mean why .Net team did not consider making it generic ?

Something like following...

```
Thread<string> th = new Thread<string>(SayHello);
```

Because many times when I pass value types to thread start I have to do boxing/unboxing.

Comment: You could easily add such a wrapper class yourself. (Also, this particular example is not boxing/unboxing, merely reference downcasting.)

Comment: Out of interest how much of a performance hit do you believe boxing/unboxing occurs as compared to the cost of starting a new thread or context switching between threads?

Comment: [Features are Unimplemented By Default](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/02/features-are-unimplemented-by-default/)

Answer (score 4):

I can see several reasons why the people who implement BCL didn't bother writing something like this:

1. If you're worried about performance, then the cast (even if it's unboxing) will be a much smaller hit than actually creating the thread.
2. If you're worried about type safety, you can easily use lambda: `new Thread(() => SayHello("Hello"))`.
3. `Thread<T>` would be a confusing type, because it's not clear what does that `T` stand for. Especially since it would have a completely different meaning than `T` in `Task<T>`.
4. If you want, you can create your `Thread<T>` as a wrapper using 20 lines (see below).

So, the issue is tiny and easy to work around if it actually bothers you and the solution could be confusing. That's most likely why resources weren't spend implementing this.

---

Possible implementation of `Thread<T>`:

```
class Thread<T>
{
    private readonly Action<T> m_action;
    private readonly Thread m_thread;
    private T m_parameter;

    public Thread(Action<T> action)
    {
        m_action = action;
        m_thread = new Thread(DoWork);
    }

    public void Start(T parameter)
    {
        m_parameter = parameter;
        m_thread.Start();
    }

    private void DoWork()
    {
        m_action(m_parameter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because no one wrote that method yet. Besides, since boxing/unboxing here is a fairly small part of the overall operation *and* few programmers actually *need* to start a thread manually (there are better abstractions for most use cases), they probably saw little need to specify, implement, test and document a change that is essentially not needed.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite easy to start a thread using a lambda to use strong-typing, so they don't need to add any new language support for it.

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Easy way to start a thread with strongly-typed multiple parameters:

        new Thread(() => MyThreadFunc("Test", 42, DateTime.Now)).Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Started thread.");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }

    static void MyThreadFunc(string param1, int param2, DateTime param3)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("param1 = {0}, param2 = {1}, param3 = {2}", param1, param2, param3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many many classes in .net which i guess would have a generic version if they were designed after the introduction of generics. Thread is just one of them.

For this specific problem, if you can use .net 4.0+:

Use the Task class in the [System.Threading.Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235608.aspx) Namespace.

```
private static void SayHello(string s)
{
    Task t = new Task(() => Console.WriteLine(s));
    t.Start();
}
```

This example is type-safe and does what your example did. The approach is different and Task does make a lot more sense if you are expecting a result, but still it´s a good replacement, i think even here. And my guess would be that MS won´t put work in the "old" Thread class, but may continue to improve the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/dd460717.aspx).

Comment: While I would generally agree with using `Task` instead of `Thread`, it doesn't do anything to solve this specific problem.

Comment: Could you explain how exactly would you use `Task` in this case? Because I really don't think it's going to help here.

Comment: The Task class it NOT a replacement for a Thread. Tasks are supposed to be short living, not for continuous operations. You should mention that.

Comment: @JustAnotherUserYouMayKnow That's what's `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` for.

Comment: In your new example, you can replace `Task` with `Thread` and it will still work. This is a reason to use lambdas, but not a reason to use `Task`. There are many reasons why `Task` is better than `Thread`, but this is not one.

Comment: As i said in one edit, Task would make much more sense if you were expecting a result. At first i confused the T in Task<T>, as it stands for result type, not the argument type. So in this case you are right. I still don´t see why one should use Thread over Task anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Due to "historical reasons". That method was created in .NET 1 (no generics) and wasn't fixed after. The same as ICloneable, etc.

Comment: But `Task` was created in .Net 4.0, uses generics and it [still has this issue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321456.aspx).

Comment: Yeah but it's easy to just use a lambda now, so there's no real benefit to them implementing arbitrary numbers of type parameters - they'd just be nasty to use and the code would look horrible.

Answer (score 0):

weird.. nobody actually asked why would anyone want to do what the OP is asking. thread is designed to run a piece of code. thread is not a method. from the nature of the generics in .NET the code new Thread() would mean a creation of an object with specific type - string. this is not anyhow related to the purpose of the Thread class to run for a while and do some stuff. complex stuff.

to illustrate my idea - this is the same as if he asked - why don't we have steamrollers equipped with TV set and XBOX...

so all in all my answer - this is not implemented because it contradicts the architecture of .NET.. ie is **wrong**and not because they didn't bother.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're saying. Thread runs a piece of code and that piece of code is a method. That method can take input, but it has to be `object`, but you can't confine it to some specific type.

Comment: Also, from the nature of generic, `new Thread<string>()` would mean creation of an object that has some relation to `string`, but it doesn't say what kind of relation it is. Why couldn't that be “this is a `Thread` that runs some code which takes `string` as an input”?